# Java Module : Export Only Class or Interface

Tags: java, class, module, export

Is it possible to export only several selected classes/interfaces across different packages within the same module ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You only can export packages; not indivudual classes or interfaces.
2. [Official docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.7.2) says "It is a compile-time error if more than one exports directive in a module declaration specifies the same package name".

So, answering your question, i woud say no; that is not possible.